# Finding the ratio of areas in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: triangles, circles, area

In the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AB:BC:CD:DA=1:9:9:8$, $AC$ intersects $BD$ at $P$, what is $S_{\triangle PAB}:S_{\triangle PBC}:S_{\triangle PCD}:S_{\triangle PDA}$?

[image: Diagram]

I have no idea how to start this question; how do I get the areas of the triangles when only given side lengths? Please help me out.

Comment: Hint: $\triangle PAB\sim \triangle PDC$ and $\triangle PBC \sim \triangle PAD$.

Comment: BCD is isoceles ... etc.

Comment: How does BCD being isosceles help me?

Comment: Nvm, I think I got it. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle PDC$. These pairs of inscribed angles are equal:

$$\begin{align*}
\angle CAB &=\angle BDC\\
\angle ABD &= \angle DCA
\end{align*}$$

So $\triangle PAB \sim\triangle PDC$. The ratio of their areas are square of the ratio of their corresponding sides:

$$\frac{S_{\triangle PAB}}{S_{\triangle PDC}} = \left(\frac{AB}{DC}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{81}$$

---

Similar, for $\triangle PBC$ and $\triangle PAD$, consider these pairs of inscribed angles,

$$\begin{align*}
\angle DBC &= \angle CAD\\
\angle BCA &= \angle ADB\\
\triangle PBC &\sim \triangle PAD\\
\frac{S_{\triangle PBC}}{S_{\triangle PAD}} &= \left(\frac{BC}{AD}\right)^2\\
& = \frac{81}{64}
\end{align*}$$

---

Between $\triangle PAB$ and $\triangle PAD$, these inscribed angles are equal because $BC = CD$:

$$\angle CAB = \angle CAD$$

Then the ratio of their areas is

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{S_{\triangle PAB}}{S_{\triangle PAD}}
&= \frac{\frac12 PA\cdot AB\sin\angle PAB}{\frac12PA\cdot AD\sin PAD}\\
&= \frac{AB}{AD}\\
&= \frac 18\\
\end{align*}$$

---

$$S_{\triangle PAB}:S_{\triangle PBC}:S_{\triangle PCD}:S_{\triangle PDA}
= 8:81:648:64
$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note,

$$\frac{PB}{PD}=\frac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_{\triangle ACD}} 
= \frac{\frac12\cdot AB\cdot BC\cdot \sin B}{\frac12\cdot AD\cdot DC\cdot \sin D}
= \frac{ AB\cdot BC}{ AD\cdot DC}=\frac{1}{8}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{PA}{PC}=\frac{ AB\cdot AD}{ BC\cdot DC}=\frac{8}{81}$$

Recognize

$$\frac{S_{\triangle PAB}}{S_{\triangle PAD}} 
=\frac{S_{\triangle PBC}}{S_{\triangle PCD}} =\frac{PB}{PD} = \frac18,\>\>\>\>\>
\frac{S_{\triangle PAB}}{S_{\triangle PBC}}=\frac{PA}{PC} = \frac8{81} $$

to obtain,

$$S_{\triangle PAB}:S_{\triangle PBC}:S_{\triangle PCD}:S_{\triangle PDA}
=8:81:648:64$$